# custom date time format

Tags: c#, datetime

i need to format date like "2010-04-21 11:35:22.440". can anyone help me?

the problem is i am seeing either 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000 or 2008-03-09 16:05:07Z but not the one i am looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"` with the ToString of the date variable.

e.g:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Comment: thanks Cybernate, i was close but you helped me get the answer!

Comment: Cybernate, your answer is still slightly off, hh formats the time in 12h format, so 23:00:00 and 11:00:00 would both output 11, you need to use HH in this case

Answer (score 5):

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) link should point you in the right direction.

Comment: +1 sicne this gives how to build any format string, not just the one in question.

Comment: @Harry, following that logic, would you +1 an answer that just links to www.stackoverflow.com, as that would answer every question, not just the one that was asked?

Comment: i agree with Patrick McDonald. I had already visited that link but was looking for something specific.

Comment: @Patrick, the difference of course being that the link needs to answer the *specific* question in addition to being a reference to solve a more general problem. If you were to link to a particular SO question that helps answer the user's question, then it would be analogous. (And just for reference, I did vote up yours and Cybernate's answers as well for having the specific solution.)

Answer (score 5):

```
string formattedDate = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:mm\\:ss.fff");
```

Note that the case of MM and HH are important, MM is months, mm is minutes, and HH is 24h, vs hh being 12h.

Also notice the time separator is specified as \:, if you just use : it will use the time separator specified in your regional settings, which may not necessarily be a colon.

Comment: thx Patrick McDonald. i like your answer as well but Cybernate posted first, so he gets the tick.

Comment: That's fine, just make sure to swap the date and time elements of the answer you accepted, and change hh to uppercase so you get 24h rather than 12h