# How to convert date format to different date format?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I need to convert the following:

```
"2015-09-18T19:00:00"
```

to

```
"2015/09/18/1900"
```

I'm able to do this a hacky way by converting the top one to a datetime and then extracting the year,month,day,hour and building the bottom string. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: If you know the exact format then you would use ParseExact to convert the string to a DateTime.  Then use ToString("fmt") to convert your DateTime to a string using the desired format.

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom date time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601160/custom-date-time-format)

Comment: Converting to a DateTime() is the proper method and not a Hack.  Any other method would be considered a hack.

Comment: Obligitory:  https://xkcd.com/1179/  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse("2015-09-18T19:00:00").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/HHmm")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string date = "2015-09-18T19:00:00";
string d= Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/HHmm");
```